# How should I keep the search screen active?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a pop-up search screen to perform search.
The issue is that the parent screen may be accidentally closed before the pop-up screen is properly closed.

What script should I add to avoid the above issues?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are you making alert dialog ?

Comment: can you show me your code....or you can check my code below in answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `dialog.setCancelable(false);` and this will make popup remain until OK button is pressed.

below is my code

```
public void HelpDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_help, null);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        alert.setCancelable(false);   //use this line in your code
        alert.setView(dialogView);
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged with JavaScript, but this looks like Java.